# Android + Firebase - sendTextMessage in background.Send sms while phone is not touched

Tags: android, android-studio, text, sms, android-service

I am struggling with android services. The purpose of app is to send text message using native system text application. The phone recieves phone numbers from Firebase and sends a message to all the numbers from the list via smsManager.sendTextMessage. I realized that few minutes after screen is locked the app stops running for no reason..

As I already said I tried to keep my app running in background with android services but it is not working. Is there any simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of way to make a Service work even when the device is in sleep mode. This depends on the feature you want to implement. As far as I have understood, mobile numbers will come from server and app will send messages to these numbers.

If you want to do it in a repeating manner, You can use [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) to start the service from time to time, and fetch the numbers and send messages.

You can also use wacklock to keep the service running all the time, but this will be more battery draining.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Battery is not a problem. I will accept answer later, first I have to read about AlarmManager and wacklock.

Comment: You can see this for wacklock... https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html#cpu

Comment: Well wacklock was a good direction but app still had problems running in background then I realized that Xiaomi has a "Power sawing app" which was "on", I turned it off and now everything is working great with wacklock.